# application crashed when I pushing new view controller to self.navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have an iOS 5 application.
When I want to push view to my navigation controller, the application crashes :(

Here's my appDelegate part:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    StartViewController *startViewController=[[StartViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:startViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController=self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here's my pushing new view controller method:

```
-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"startPressed: called");
    //loading RootViewController (mainscreen view)
    RootViewController *rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Application crashed at a string `[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];`

Help me, please. How to solve this problem?

Comment: There is something wrong in your, see my answer. But please provide the crash log.

Comment: I think something wrong in dealing with automatic reference counting mode. I think something I missed. It's my first ios 5 application with automatic reference counting mode enabled in it

Comment: application is very simple. I have only one button start in my startViewController. when user presses it I;m trying to load RootViewController. But app crashed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem. I changed `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO] and debug gave me the warning that the view outlet was not set. So I connected view from interface builder and the problem is gone. Thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 4):

A UINavigationController wants a rootviewController:

```
StartViewController *startViewController=[[StartViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewControllr:startViewController];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

---

Change the

```
@autoreleasepool { 
     return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); 
}
```

to

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); 
[pool release];

return retVal;
```

Comment: crash log: `@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }` SIGABRT here

Comment: In debug, when pressing stop button after crash: `error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 2184 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "void macosx_kill_inferior_safe()": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)`

Comment: Also try running the app with `NSZombieEnabled`.

Comment: NSAutorelease pool is unavailable in automatic reference counting mode

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange way to deal with UINavigationController. In your case I would like to know if it works if you change

```
self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

StartViewController *startViewController=[[StartViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:startViewController animated:YES];
```

to

```
StartViewController *startViewController=[[StartViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startViewController];
```

If your app still crashes, it would be interesting to know if you override `-loadView` method of `StartViewController` class as you don't initialize it with `– initWithNibName:bundle:`

Comment: Please clarify about -loadView method.

Comment: maybe you mean `viewDidLoad` method? I can initialize it with `- initWithNibName:bundle: but application will crash.

Comment: StartViewController is working fine. But When I'm trying to push my new view controller to self.navigationController app crashes :(

Comment: So eliminate RootViewController of the equation. Load directly an UIViewController instead and check if your application still crash again

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean "eliminate RootVoewController" of the equation?

Comment: Try to push a basic UIViewController instead of your own RootViewController

Comment: It works when I push `UIViewController *vc=[[UIViewController alloc] init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Comment: So the problem is in your RootViewController class. Try to spot it here

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem with pushViewController but when i try something like this

```
UINavigationController *rootViewController = (UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
NSLog(@"NavControler:%@, %@", self.navigationController, rootViewController);
```

i get the same pointres, and the NSArray have 1 item.
The problem is somewhere else.

If someone can help and add some code that will work to pushViewController because i have the correct NavigationController but when i try to push the ViewControler i get error

```
  ViewController* NextView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *rootViewController = (UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
[rootViewController pushViewController:NextView animated:YES];
```

Please could someone explained this issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also have some issue with pushViewController. I checked all target memberships and obtain that my xib file wasn't added to necessary target. This helps me.
I think you also should check your xib file.